# For the function ()=(16/^2), simplify each expression as much as possible.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the function ()=(16/^2), simplify each expression as much as possible.

1. ((+ℎ)−())/ℎ, ℎ≠0:
2. (()−())/−, ≠:

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: What don't you understand? just write all the $f(stuff)$ ans $\frac {16}{stuff^2}$ and then do all the math to simplify.  It's ... work.  But it's straight forwards and unless you tell us where you have problems there's no reason you shouldn't be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\frac{16}{(x+h)^2}-\frac{16}{x^2}}{h}=\frac{\frac{16[x^2-(x+h)^2]}{x^2(x+h)^2}}{h}=\frac{16(x-x-h)(x+x+h)}{hx^2(x+h)^2}=\frac{16h(2x+h)}{hx^2(x+h)^2}=\frac{16(2x+h)}{x^2(x+h)^2}=\frac{16}{x(x+h)^2}+\frac{16}{x^2(x+h)}$$

$$\frac{f(w)-f(x)}{w-x}=\frac{\frac{16}{w^2}-\frac{16}{x^2}}{w-x}=\frac{16(x^2-w^2)}{w^2x^2(w-x)}=-\frac{16(w+x)}{w^2x^2}$$